# Temporary pause RabbitMQ consummer

Tags: go, rabbitmq

I'm writing consumer for RabbitMQ with Go which has to pause message consumption for some time and then recover to consume messages from queue again.
While reading documentation https://godoc.org/github.com/streadway/amqp I was unable to determinate the mechanism which I need to implement in my code.

Is it possible to do that? Have an example?

Snippet of my code:

```golang
rabbitMQMessages, err = ch.Consume(
        "TestQ",
        "testConsumer",
        false,
        true,
        false,
        false,
        nil,
    )
    failOnError(err, "Failed to register a consumer")

    forever := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        select {
        case d := <-rabbitMQMessages: // Cheking if messge was recieved
            log.Printf("Received a message: %s", d.Body)
            dotcount := bytes.Count(d.Body, []byte("."))

            err = ch.Flow(false) // Returns error: Exception (540) Reason: "NOT_IMPLEMENTED - active=false
            failOnError(err, "Failed to close channel")

            t := time.Duration(dotcount)
            time.Sleep(t * time.Second)
            log.Printf("Done")

            err = ch.Flow(true)

            d.Ack(false)
        default:
            log.Println("Default section")
        }
    }()

    log.Printf(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C")
    <-forever
```

Comment: I've never used that library, but simply searching the linked docs for "pause" shows the [Flow](https://godoc.org/github.com/streadway/amqp#Channel.Flow) method. Is that not what you need?

Comment: @Flimzy I was aware of that method. Unfothunalty it doesn't do that, o I don't know how to use it. I'm getting an error once I try to pause it. ```Exception (540) Reason: "NOT_IMPLEMENTED - active=false"```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out. I need to `Close` connection and then reopen it. This prevents messages from got read in upfront. Not sure if it the right way but it worked for me. Adding a snippet of my test code.

```golang
func main() {
    var rabbitMQMessages <-chan amqp.Delivery
    var err error
    var rabbitMQ RabbitMQ

    err = rabbitMQ.dial()
    failOnError(err, "Failed to connect to RabbitMQ")
    defer rabbitMQ.Close()

    err = rabbitMQ.setUpChannel()
    failOnError(err, "Failed to open a channel")

    err = rabbitMQ.Consumme()
    failOnError(err, "Failed to consume")

    log.Printf(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C")

    rabbitMQMessages = rabbitMQ.GetChan()

    for {
        select {
        case d, ok := <-rabbitMQMessages: // Cheking if messge was recieved
            log.Printf("Chan status at start of function %t", ok)

            if !ok {
                err = rabbitMQ.setUpChannel()
                failOnError(err, "Unable to open channel")
                defer rabbitMQ.Close()

                err = rabbitMQ.Consumme()
                failOnError(err, "Recover. Failed to register a consumer")

                rabbitMQMessages = rabbitMQ.GetChan()

                continue
            }

            log.Printf("Chan status at later of function %t", ok)

            log.Printf("Received a message: %s", d.Body)
            dotcount := bytes.Count(d.Body, []byte("."))
            d.Ack(false)

            err = rabbitMQ.CloseChannel()
            failOnError(err, "Failed to close channel")
            t := time.Duration(dotcount)
            time.Sleep(t * time.Second)
            log.Printf("Done")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should [cancel the consumer](https://godoc.org/github.com/streadway/amqp#Channel.Cancel), then re-run `ch.Consume` at the time you wish to resume consuming messages.